# Converting an array of objects into a matrix in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, matrix

I have an array of objects like this:

```
"result": [
        {
            "UserGroupName": "TestCronGroup2",
            "CourseTitle": "Test Publish Course 1",
            "ComplianceStatus": false
        },
        {
            "UserGroupName": "TestCronGroup2",
            "CourseTitle": "test456",
            "ComplianceStatus": null
        },
        {
            "UserGroupName": "TestCronGroup2",
            "CourseTitle": "retest456",
            "ComplianceStatus": null
        },
        {
            "UserGroupName": "TestCronGroup1",
            "CourseTitle": "Test Publish Course 1",
            "ComplianceStatus": false
        },
```

And I want it to convert it in a matrix form like this:

[Compliance Report Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViC0S.png)

This is my code so far. I am unable to link the values in matrix properly:

```
showItems = (columns: any) => {
    var columnsArr = new Array();
    columnsArr = [
      {
        title: "Course",
        field: "CourseTitle",
      },
    ];

    Object.keys(this.props.complianceReport).forEach((key, index) => {
      var columnsObj = {
        title: this.props.complianceReport[key].UserGroupName,
      };
      columnsArr.push(columnsObj);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <ReportsTable
          columns={columnsArr}
          tableData={this.props.complianceReport}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

What I am able to achieve so far:
[My Matrix so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyy6G.png)

I am new to react and javascript so any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things you should start to prepare data for react-table output. First thing is to create array of all the columns (course and unique usergroups) and second array of the unique courses.

```
  // prep columns (usergroups unique)
  // use Set to aviod duplicates
  let userGroups = new Set();
  result.forEach(item => userGroups.add(item.UserGroupName));
  let columns = Array.from(userGroups)
    .sort()
    .map(item => {
      return {
        Header: item,
        accessor: item
      };
    });

  // add column: Courses in front
  columns.unshift({ Header: "Courses", accessor: "courses" });

  // prep courses (unique)
  let courseTitles = new Set();
  result.forEach(item => courseTitles.add(item.CourseTitle));
  const courseTitlesItems = Array.from(courseTitles).sort();
```

When you have both of these you can iterate through all the courses and check if it is available for specific usergroup.

```
  // prep data
  let data = courseTitlesItems.map(courseItem => {
    return {
      ...columns.reduce(
        (o, column) =>
          Object.assign(o, {
            [column.accessor]: testCourse(result, courseItem, column)
          }),
        {}
      ),
      courses: courseItem
    };
  });
```

Use this function to test for data.

```
function testCourse(result, courseItem, column) {
  const foundItem = result.find(
    resultItem =>
      resultItem.CourseTitle === courseItem &&
      resultItem.UserGroupName === column.accessor
  );

  return foundItem === undefined || foundItem.ComplianceStatus === null
    ? "-"
    : foundItem.ComplianceStatus === false
    ? "No"
    : "Yes";
}
```

Demo and the playground I used to solve your quiz. Hope you will find it useful!
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-vr0ky?file=/src/App.js